# laravel not class found in deployment server

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel 4 application working fine on my local machine. I've cloned it onto my VPS. When I run composer install or composer update, I get errors that "class not found". I've checked vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php and my classes are there. The class is located in the standard app/models/. I removed some code, which finally allowed the composer to update. However none of my custom classes all located inside app/models are being loaded. Any ideas what's going on? Thanks.

Local: php version 5.5.10
VPS: php version 5.5.9

Edit: Included error log

```
[2014-10-23 02:50:37] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'Role' not found' in ../app/routes.php:214
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

Role.php is located in app/models/

Edit2: Added route

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth.admin'), function() {

    $roles  = new Role();

    Route::get('/help', array(
        'as' => 'help',
        'uses' => 'HelpController@getHelp'
    ));
}
```

This isn't the full route, but that's essential it. Everything works fine on local machine also.

Comment: Please post your error here to let us know more detail.

Comment: Updated the post with the error log. thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your routes.php? This seems like a namespacing-issue.

Comment: Everything do seem fine; does `composer update` and `composer dumpautoload` complete without errors?

Comment: Check that your `Role` class is inside the `Role.php` file. If you develop on Windows machine, the file name is case insensible while your Linux VPS cares the differences between `Role.php` and `role.php`

Comment: composer complained about the same error. I commented out the $roles = new Role() and the composer was able to run. Then when I load the page, I get that error in the error log.

Comment: I double checked it, both are Role. I did a git clone of the code, so they should be identical. My local machine is mac and my vps is ubuntu.

Comment: Have you checked if those classes are in the autoloader? I really think it's not getting autoloaded

Comment: Where is your `Role.php` which defines your `Role` class located?

Comment: - my Role.php is located in app/models/

Comment: I checked vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php and saw this 'Role' => $baseDir . '/app/models/Role.php',
This is what I expect as that's exactly the same on my local machine.

Comment: I've also tried blindly copying my entire web/ directory from my local machine onto the vps (including the vendor directory) and it has the exact same problem. Now I'm wondering if there's something wrong with my vps settins?

Comment: Thank you everyone. It was an issue with short tags. I posted an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem with the help of others. MY VPS did not support short tags. My Role.php began with `<?`. I corrected it with `<?php` and everything works.